# HTTP Post To PHP

Tags: php, blackberry

I am developing an application where i will need to collect user-unput and send to a PHP script on the server.I searched and got some code which showed me how to use a class for posting the data ...but the data does not get posted to the server.Where am i missing it?..Below is some of my code..

```
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
  import net.rim.device.api.system.*;

   /**
    * 
  */
  class IntroPage extends MainScreen{
// private members - these represent the "controls"
    private BasicEditField identifierfield = null;
    private BasicEditField datafield = null;
      private ButtonField submitbutton = null;
    private LabelField statusfield = null;
    IntroPage() { 
   super(); 
   setTitle("BB IBM Demo App");
   identifierfield = new BasicEditField("Identifier: ","",50, EditField.NO_NEWLINE );    
    // add this field to the screen
    add(identifierfield);

    // create a field for the data of our transaction
    datafield = new BasicEditField("Data: ","",100, EditField.NO_NEWLINE );    
    // add this field to the screen
    add(datafield);
    // createlistener
    FieldChangeListener listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                ButtonField submitbutton = (ButtonField) field;
               String id=identifierfield.getText();
               String data=datafield.getText();
               if(id.trim().length()==0||data.trim().length()==0)
               {
                Dialog.alert("Please Fill In All Fields.");
                return;  }
                if(bb_ibm_transaction.ProcessTransaction(id,data)==true)
                {
                   Dialog.alert("Your Data Has Been Saved Successfully");  }
                else
                {
                 Dialog.alert("There Was An Error Saving Your Details,Please Try Again Later.");    }
}
        }; 

    // create a button to submit our transaction
    submitbutton = new ButtonField("Submit Transaction",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    submitbutton.setChangeListener(listener);


    // add this button to the screen
    add(submitbutton);

    // add a status label
    statusfield = new LabelField("Please enter transaction data.");
```

When i click on the submit button..i get the "There was an error saving your details" dialogue...(which means the connection class does not echo 'success'...thereby returns false)
Below is the code for the Connection class:

```
    import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.URLEncodedPostData;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
   import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
    /**
    * 
   */
   class bb_ibm_transaction {
  bb_ibm_transaction() {    }
 // this method interacts with the server
 public static boolean ProcessTransaction(String id,String data)
{
    // default to non-success return code
    boolean ret = false;

    // some variables necessary for HTTP communication
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;


    // because many of the steps can throw an exception, wrap this method in           try/catch block
    try
    {

        StringBuffer returnStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String returnString = new String();


        String desiredEncoding = "ISO-8859-1";


        URLEncodedPostData params = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, true);
        params.append("identifier", id);
        params.append("data", data);

        String url = "http://localhost/mob/test.php?" + params.toString();

        System.out.println(url);


        //Connecting to Server
        httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        inputStream = httpConnection.openDataInputStream();

        if(httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            int ch;

            //Process Response

            // check header field for a specific encoding
            String contenttype = httpConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            if (contenttype != null)
            {
                contenttype = contenttype.toUpperCase();
                if (contenttype.indexOf("UTF-8") != -1)
                {
                    desiredEncoding = "UTF-8";
                }
            }

            // get an inputstreamreader to handle utf-8 data
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,desiredEncoding);

            while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) 
            {
                returnStringBuffer.append((char) ch);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            httpConnection.close();
            inputStream = null;
            httpConnection = null;
            returnString = returnStringBuffer.toString();

            // examine return string
            if (returnString.indexOf("SUCCESS") != -1)
            {
                ret = true;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        httpConnection.close();
        inputStream = null;
        httpConnection = null;
        //Bad Transaction.
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error occurred in ProcessTransaction(" + id + "," + data + ")\n" + e.toString());
        return ret;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
            if (httpConnection != null)
                httpConnection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
    }


}
  }
```

And this is the php script

```
   <?php
   include 'mob_connect.php';
   $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['id']);
 if($id)
{
echo "SUCCESS";
}
 ?>
```

Where am i missing it?.

Comment: anything interesting in the server logs?

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or in the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

You should to use HTTP POST method in your application.

Try to show all input in PHP:

```
<?php
// GET method
print_r($_GET);

// POST method 
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Also, read this http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml

You need this

```
// Set the request method to POST 
hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If testing on the simulator add `;interface=wifi` to your url and use `Default WLAN Network` as your simulated WiFi network.
2. Check whether you're getting an HTTP response code from the server. In your ProcessTransaction method move the line `inputStream = httpConnection.openDataInputStream();` inside the `if` statement, then debug to see if you get an `HTTP_OK` response from your server. If you do, you know the connection is working and it's something to do with your PHP script or the way you're processing it. If not, it's your network connection.

If you are using OS5 or above you might want to check out the [`ConnectionFactory`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html) class which can do the 'heavy lifting' of determining what type of connections are available to your BlackBerry (WiFi, 3G, EDGE etc) and creating the URL for you.